# Can't Get Variable into Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

The `percent` variable gets "alerted" just fine.  But, when I put it in the `progressbar` function, just defaults to zero.  It will work if I hardcode the value i.e. `value: 60`.  How can I make it work with my `percent` variable?  Thanks.

```
    function updateProgress(percent)
    {
        alert(percent);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: percent
        });
    }
```

Comment: could `percent` be a `string`?

Comment: Try `val = {value:percent};` and then pass in like `$("#progressbar").progressbar(val);`

Comment: You need to make sure `percent` isn't a `string` you could always `parseFloat(percent)` in your function to make sure

Comment: Kyle is right, it was a string!

Comment: what plugin are you using, and what type is percent of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updateProgress (percent) {
  alert(percent);

  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: parseFloat(percent)
  });
}
```

Comment: This is what I used from Kyle's comment.  This is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: just on a footnote: i like really like this syntax `+percent` (get the number value of a string)

Comment: I dont think, he should use `parseInt`. After all its a percentage, and `parseFloat` should be a better choice

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the variable percent is a string here so convert it to an integer or better a float:

```
value: parseFloat(percent)
```

Comment: I cannot get the string-with-percent method to work. Are you sure that is valid?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Try this:

```
function updateProgress(percent)
{
    var progress = {
        value: percent
    };
    alert(progress.value);
    $("#progressbar").progressbar(progress);
}
```